# How do you change the order of explanatory and response variables in a mosaic plot?

Tags: r, mosaic-plot

My [work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jamDd.jpg).
What I [want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auVmp.jpg).
How can I modify my R code so that my explanatory variables (Captured, Not Captured) are on the bottom part of my plot, the response variables (Captured, Not Captured) on the right side of my plot? My teacher is not accepting my mosaic plot, because: (1) my x- and y-axis extrude (2) the explanatory variables should be on the bottom (3) the response variables should be on the right. I really hope someone can help me out.. I've been trying on YT but I can't find anything. I attached my R code below.

Thanks in advance!

```
mosaictable <- matrix (c (3, 9, 22, 21), byrow = T, ncol = 2)
rownames (mosaictable) = c ("White", "Blue ")
colnames (mosaictable) = c ("Captured", "Not Captured")
mosaicplot  ((mosaictable), sub = "Pigeon Color", ylab = "Relative frequency", 
            col = c ("firebrick", "goldenrod1"), font = 2, main = "Mosaic Plot of Pigeon Color and Their Capture Rate"
            
            )
axis (1)
axis (4)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a better expected output. I'm not sure what it should look like

Comment: @starja. Yeah, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @starja, I want my mosaic plot to be sitting on an x-axis, the variables on the bottom and on the right of the mosaic plot, with the relative frequency on the left (y-axis).

Comment: Hi.. avoid posting the same question twice. Please choose to keep one.